# Changing Message Sequence Chart (MSC) Tool for Doxygen

Tags: charts, doxygen

I'd like to know whether there is a way to change the default tool to generate message sequence charts (msc) of Doxygen. Actual default tool for Doxygen is the mscgen (http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/) and it's a good tool, but I'd like to use msc-gen (https://sites.google.com/site/mscgen2393/) that seems to be a more complete tool.

I've already tried to create a link at "MSCGEN_PATH = /usr/bin/" to the msc-gen (like ln -s /usr/bin/msc-gen ./mscgen) but command line of tools are different. There is a specific way to configure Doxygen to "learn" this new tool command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the current msc-gen version (v4.0.0), your solution should work.
I just tried setting the MSCGEN_PATH to the msc-gen installation directory and it worked for me. msc-gen already brings a copy of its main executable with the name `mscgen.exe` to be called by doxygen.

This solution is also described in the second paragraph of:
http://msc-generator.sourceforge.net/help/4.0/

You may also like to have a look at Plant UML and its doxygen integration:

- http://plantuml.com/index.html
- http://plantuml.com/doxygen.html